# DatePicker not showing in modal dialog using react and mantine

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, mantine

I am having problem with a modal dialog. I am using **react** and **mantine**. THe dialog is using a DatePicker but as you can see the DataPicker is not fully visible it is bound to the parents size. How can I show the DatePicker using it full width ? I think it has to do with some styling but no idea what to change.

See the picture for an the example

[image]

Comment: try to add modal dialog height,or check parent element css style, if `overflow` is `hidden`, try to set `overflow: visible;`

Comment: Post your code.

Answer (score 1):

Adding `popoverProps={{ zIndex: 10000 }}` worked for me with Mantine `DateTimePicker`.

`withPortal: true` is not part of the properties in the mantine popoverProps.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. I add this property to the DatePicker component  and then it works ok

popoverProps={{ withinPortal: true }}

Answer (score 0):

use `<DatePickerInput popoverProps={{ withinPortal: true }} />`

source: https://github.com/mantinedev/mantine/issues/4546